When archiving with NLog, how can I preserve the original file name?
I understand that NLog's archive mechanism renames the original file before archiving it, and then opens a new file using the original configuration's file name.
For example:

log-20240419.log (current file name)
log-20240419-1.log (original file created initially, renamed during archiving)

However, my requirement now is to include the time (HHmmss) in the file name:

log-20240419-101558.log

And when reaching the specified capacity limit, start a new file for logging:

log-20240419-102034.log

How can I configure NLog.config or achieve this from C# code?
I've searched for similar issues, but it seems that I haven't found a solution.
NLog Archive File keeping original file name
